# Would rim brakes help a slightly bent rim?

Tags: brakes, wheel-truing

After recently falling and bending the rim a bit I was wondering if forcefully applying the brakes while in motion help it straighten a bit?

Might be my imagination but it seems much truer than right after the fall after constantly applying the brake.

Comment: No.  But it's possible that the wheel realigned itself slightly as the stresses in the spokes equalized.  Also, of course, the brakes will wear faster when the wheel is bent and so the gap between wheel and pad will grow.

Comment: @DanielRHicks when a wheel goes out of true because of a fall, does that mean the the spokes have lost tension as well and need to be tightened again to re-true?

Comment: It means something has "given" -- either the spokes have stretched or the rim has bent or some such.  In general, you attempt to correct the problem by adjusting the spokes, though there's a limit to how well that can work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to the question is, **no**.

Consider and compare the braking force to the other acting forces, and which would overcome the other; drive side and non-drive side **spokes pulling radially and laterally** on the wheel (this can be quite a high amount of force when adding all of the spokes together. It takes all of your weight, as well as any impacts you sustain while riding.) **Rotational force and momentum** is another major factor, and it is often at or well above your weight. The amount of force that a road caliper can apppy (or any caliper) is well below any of these other forces. A disc brake may be an exception, since I've heard of extreme circumstances in which a disc brake could actually rip a hub from a rim, but that has little to do with the lateral true of a rim.

Another component, directly related to you question of being "in motion", is that the braking power of most calipers is not perfectly symmetrical, because of caliper design or because of imperfect setup. With these asymmetrical and off-center forces, the rim is often pushed to one side creating a high/low tension in the spokes between either side. The asymmetrical and off-center force also create a certain amount of twisting in the wheel that has a similar rotation as that of the nipples threading onto the spokes.

*In essence, braking always has a deteriorative effect on trueness.*

Answer (score 2):

No way the brakes trued the wheels.

Now it is possible the brakes realigned in a way they rubbed less.